# Javascript website scraping using WebKit and Selenium tools

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, webkit

I tried scraping a javascript website using two tools, both didn't work.
The website link is: http://xx.xxx.com/category-499399872.htm
The relevant text I'm trying to extract is **GY-68...**:

```
<div class="item3line1">

    <dl class="item " data-id="38952795780">
        <dt class="photo">
            <a target="_blank" href="//item.xxx.com/item.htm?spm=a1z10.5-c.w4002-6778075404.11.54MDOI&id=38952795780" data-spm-wangpu-module-id="4002-6778075404" data-spm-anchor-id="a1z10.5-c.w4002-6778075404.11">
                <img src="//img.xxx.com/bao/uploaded/i4/TB1HMt3FFXXXXaFaVXXXXXXXXXX_!!0-item_pic.jpg_240x240.jpg" alt="GY-68 BMP180 新款 BOSCH温度 气压传感器模块 代替BMP085"></img>
            </a>
        </dt>
```

I'm trying to match the class="item " bit as a preliminary venture:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver
import time

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://xxxx.com/category-499399872.htm')
print browser.title

time.sleep(120)    
content = browser.find_element_by_class_name('item ')
print content
browser.quit()

display.stop()
```

I get:

> ```
> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"item "}
> ```

---

I also tried using WebKit - i know the site renders okay in WebKit because i tested with *rekonq*
Here, i get the page (in Chinese) but the actual/relevant data is not there. WebKit's supposed to run the Javascript and give me the final results but I don't think that's happening.

```
import sys
from io import StringIO
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *
from lxml import html
from lxml import etree

#Take this class for granted.Just use result of rendering.
class Render(QWebPage):
  def __init__(self, url):
    self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    QWebPage.__init__(self)
    self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)
    self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))
    self.app.exec_()

  def _loadFinished(self, result):
    self.frame = self.mainFrame()
    self.app.quit()

url = 'http://xxxx.com/category-499399872.htm'
r = Render(url) #returns a Render object
result = r.frame.toHtml() #returns a QString
result_utf8 = result.toUtf8() #returns a QByteArray of utf8 data

#QByteArray->str->unicode
#contents = StringIO(unicode(result_utf8.data(), "utf-8"))
data = result_utf8.data() #returns byte string
print(data)

element = html.fromstring(data)
print(element.tag)

for img in element.xpath('//dl[@class="item "]/dt[@class="photo"]/a/img'):
    print(img.get('alt'))

#archive_links = html.fromstring(str(result.toAscii()))
#print archive_links.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/dl[1]/dt/a/img")
```

Basically I want a list of parts the seller has to offer that I can *grep, sort, uniq*. I also tried **elinks** and lynx with ECMAScript but that was too basic and didn't work.

Comment: There is no element with the class name "col-main" in the html snippet you provided?

Comment: darn, sorry about that, i'll correct it - i'm not able to match any of those attributes 'photo' or  'item-name' - in fact none of that exists for some mysterious reason WebKit is not executing the JS or something.. Anyway yeah i was working on those scripts and changing things but they are essentially correct - will fix

Comment: grr! "photo" or "item " are missing from the webkit output to the best of my knowledge

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a silly suggestion, but you are trying to find an element by class name "col-main" while the example code has a class name of "item-name".

Answer (score 0):

There is a space in the class name it is 'item ' not 'item'.For that you have to rewrite the xpath as

```
  //dl[@class="item "]/dt[@class="photo"]/a/img
```

There is an option to override that.You can use `normalize-space()` function which strips leading and trailing white-space from a string.

```
  //dl[normalize-space(@class)="item"]/dt[@class="photo"]/a/img
```

Or you can go with

```
  //a[@class='item-name']
```

also refers to the element and the text is equal to the img's alt attribute